# Youtube iOS player issues (youtube-ios-player-helper)

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-iframe-api

I have added youtube sdk player
youtube-ios-player-helper library in the iOS app which is the official library.

I am facing some issues in it :-

1. Sometimes after playing the video. I can just hear the audio and can't see the video playing.
2. Facing some random crash while playing/stopping (Refer below screenshot)

[image]

As this library uses UIWebView and render iFrame with Javascript.
I don't know how to fix it as it seems like javascript issue. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: show your tried  code

Comment: I am not a javascript developer so I don't know what to change. Thats why I posted here.

Comment: show your class code

Comment: There is ytPlayerView class. 
I just call the method. [cell.ytPlayerView loadWithVideoId:entry.videoId];
I have written this code in cellForRow delegate of UITableView.

Comment: plz add where you added the  ytPlayerView in your class

Comment: Where I can share? Can you please suggests?

Comment: plz add here...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184747/discussion-between-awesome-apple-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 0):

Do you add delegate implementation of the YTPlayerView object in viewDidLoad ?
Just in case.

like…

```
player.delegate = self
```

So in code it look some like this…

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, YTPlayerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var player: YTPlayerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    playerView.delegate = self
    playerView.load(withVideoId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

}
```